# Excel: replacing numbers only if it's at the beginning of text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to replace/substitute the "00" in Column A only if the cell starts with "00" to (00) -- so in the example below, only A6 would have a change. Can someone help with a formula? The image is linked to my question for reference,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to put the formula in Column B:

`=IF(LEFT(A2,2) = "00", "(00)"&RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-2), A2)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly youre looking to use, but if you are using VBA - Here is an example of a line:

```
[YOUR CODE]

Set datasheet = Sheet1
FinalDataCell = datasheet.Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For I = 1 To FinalDataCell
    If Left(Cells(I, 1).Value, 2) = "00" Then
    cell.Value = ""
    End If
    Next I

[THE REST OF YOUR CODE]
```

My computer isnt pulling up your picture, unfortunately, but I hope this works for you!